# Converting bulk Mailboxes in Office365 to Shared Mailbox

Tags: microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office, mailbox, sysadmin

It would be practical to as a sysadmin to convert parallelly the mailboxes of more than a user to shared? In the O365 admin console off course.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can convert as many mailboxes as you like to shared mailboxes.

Comment: @joeqwerty you are right, i edited the question